# How to check response time of a website with javascript?

Tags: javascript, httpwebrequest, stopwatch

I check response time of a website in c# with httpwebrequest and measure the time with stopwatch. How to do a webrequest and a good way as stopwatch to check the time with javascript?

Here is my c# sample.

```
 Uri URL = new Uri("http://www.example.com");                    
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
 request.Timeout = 10000;
 Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
 stopWatch.Start();
 HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
 response.Close();
 stopWatch.Stop();
 int ms = stopWatch.Elapsed.Milliseconds;
```

Comment: What do you mean by javascript? Is this 'from the browser'? If so, the browsers cross-domain policy may be a problem. Is it your own site you want to measure, or just sites in general?

Comment: yes from browser and my website. actually I am trying to create a webpage to show my servers response time.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in any good way since you cannot connect to arbitrary websites using JavaScript.

While you could try abusing `script`, `iframe` or `img` tags for this it would be a pretty ugly hack. But in this case you'd measure the time between setting the `src` attribute (assuming the element is already in the DOM) and its onload event firing.

---

Since you want to show response times of your servers consider using something like [SmokePing](http://oss.oetiker.ch/smokeping/). Your run it on the server and it generates you pretty awesome graphs from the data it gathers.

Comment: so how to do this? what should I use except javascript?

Comment: Thanks for answer. I created a tool with c# like smokeping. Now I want to create a webpage which can do similar mesurements but i am new for webpage development so i dont have anyidea what to use. it doesn't have to be javascript. It can be php or sth else.

Comment: A server-side programming language is much more appropriate. However, why not just use SmokePing instead of re-inventing the wheel?